# TypeError: (0 , _fflate.unzipSync) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'am using jest to run my unit test by fflat to unzip/zip file in electron environment, but jest throw a error: **TypeError: (0 , _fflate.unzipSync) is not a function**.

```
    import {
      copy,
      emptyDir,
      outputFile,
      pathExists,
      readFile,
      remove,
    } from 'fs-extra';
    
    import { IReadProfileParams } from './types';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { unzipSync } from 'fflate';
    
    async function readProfile(params: IReadProfileParams) {
      try {
        const { profilePath, tmpPath, resPath, tempResPath } = params;
        const profileData = await readFile(profilePath);
        const unzipped = unzipSync(profileData);
    
        // copy resource and file
        await emptyDir(tmpPath);
        const promises = [];
        for (const key of Object.keys(unzipped)) {
          if (unzipped[key].length) {
            const filePath = join(tmpPath, key);
            promises.push(outputFile(filePath, unzipped[key]));
          }
        }
        await Promise.all(promises);
        // profile res => temp profile res
        await copy(resPath, tempResPath, { overwrite: true });
        await remove(resPath);
       } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
       }
      }
```

The function unzipSync works well in my really application, but it can not run in jest test. It means the fflate moudule work well。 Should I make some test configs?
My jest.config.js is bellow:

```
module.ex

    ports = {
      collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/renderer/src/utils/**/index.ts'],
      moduleNameMapper: {
        '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/renderer/src/$1',
        'src/renderer/src/constants/path.ts': '<rootDir>/mocks/func.js',
      },
      runner: 'jest-electron/runner',
      testEnvironment: 'jest-electron/environment',
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/renderer/**/*.test.ts'],
      setupFiles: ['./test/setup.js'],
    };
```

I attemp to import fflate in setup.js, but it doesn't work too.setup.js is bellow:

```
import * as fflate from 'fflate';
    const fkill = require('fkill');
    const { app } = require('./electron/app');
    
    exports.mochaGlobalSetup = async () => {
      await app.start();
      app.browserWindow.focus();
      app.browserWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    };
    
    exports.mochaGlobalTeardown = async () => {
      if (app && app.isRunning()) {
        await app.stop();
      }
      await fkill(":8238", {
        force:true
      });
    };
```

It also confuse me very mush is that it will throw **fs.rm is not a function**, but readFile method will not. They are all imported from fs-extra.
[fs.rm is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPXb.png)

```
import {
      copy,
      emptyDir,
      outputFile,
      pathExists,
      readFile,
      remove,
    } from 'fs-extra';
    
    import { IReadProfileParams } from './types';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { unzipSync } from 'fflate';
    
    async function readProfile(params: IReadProfileParams) {
      try {
        const { profilePath, tmpPath, resPath, tempResPath } = params;
        const profileData = await readFile(profilePath);
        await remove(resPath);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    
      }
    }
```

All this works well in my really application, but failed in jest.